# Ag-grid How I can selected row by onContextMenu?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to select the entire line by onContextMenu. How can I do it? Example https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-table-context-menu-2-d4z64g

I try to use node.selectedRow(true), but aggrid doesn't deselect previous selected row.